# How Can I Get Ubuntu 16.04 To Work With Newer Hardware?

Tags: unity, touchpad, lenovo, hardware

So I have a budget laptop acquires in August of 2018. It came with Windows 10 on it, yeah that was a great idea... The newer versions of Ubuntu work fine, as do other distros such as Fedora 29. However, on Ubuntu 16.04, not everything works out of the box, such as the Touchpad. On newer versions it does. What is the reason for this? Does it have to do with the kernel version? Can I get 16.04 to function the same way?

Specs

Laptop Model: Lenovo [Ideapad 330-15IGM](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/330-14igm_330-15igm_330-15icn_330-15arr_330touch-15arr_hmm_201805.pdf)

Processor: Intel Celeron N4100 1.10 GHz

RAM: 4GB DDR4 2400 MHz

Graphics: Intel Graphics UHD 600

Hard Drive: 500GB Toshiba HDD

Network Adapter: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless

Comment: Yes, it has to do with the kernel version.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is it possible to upgrade the kernel to get it to work?

Comment: Using the latest 16.04 - please note the number at the end, 16.04.x - should give a fairly recent kernel. But if 18.04 which is also LTS works better why not use that? Newer hardware prefers newer releases.

Comment: I'm one of the few people that loves Unity and when Unity 8 was abandoned I try to stick to 16.04 as long as possible.

Comment: You can install the same Unity in 18.04.

Comment: I've heard that you can do so however I remember people saying that it had issues when doing that.

Comment: Some annoying pop-up error maybe but it works.

Comment: Are you using the HWE?  [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack)

Comment: 16.04.5 (or 16.04.6) comes with the 4.15 kernel, and version of Xorg which came on 18.04. So if installing with that doesn't work, then the problem is something else than kernel or xorg stack. Probably udev configuration changes.

Comment: Ooops... I just noticed the .iso file I have is an older version of 16.04 so I'll go ahead and give 16.04.6 a shot and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Guides exist which explain how to change to Unity on 18.04 LTS, from sources such as [It's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/), [LinuxConfig](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-unity-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux), and [LinuxBabe](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-unity-desktop-ubuntu-18-04-lts).

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

Choose your login manager, then run

```
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

At reboot, click on your login name and then select **Unity** when prompted to **Select Desktop Environment**.  Should you wish to remove GNOME, do

```
$ sudo apt remove gnome-shell
```